# Rails - Render each do block in js partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

How can I render a `.each do block in a js partial in Rails?

In my `messages.js.erb` file, I currently have:

```
<% @conversations.each do |convo| %>
    <%= j render "message_listing", convo: convo %>
<% end %>
$('#conversations-body-container').append(
    // APPEND RESULTS OF PREVIOUS .EACH DO RENDER
);
```

How can I go about appending the first block of code in my HTML using j render?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do like below:

```
<% @conversations.each do |convo| %>
    $('#conversations-body-container').append('<%= j render "message_listing", convo: convo %>');
<% end %>
```

Or

```
<% @conversations.each do |convo| %>
    $('<%= j render "message_listing", convo: convo %>').appendTo('#conversations-body-container');
<% end %>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I'll accept the answer when it lets me do so in 11 minutes :)